# How to find the row associated with the min/max of a column?

Tags: sql, t-sql

So basically I have some simple SQL code that looks like the following;

```
SELECT 
       [Column1]
      ,[Column2]
      ,[Column3]
      ,[Column4]
      ,MIN([Column5]) AS maxColumn5
      ,MAX([Column6]) AS minColumn6
      ,SUM([Column7]) AS sumColumn7
      ,SUM([Column8]) AS sumColumn8
      ,SUM([Column9]) AS sumColumn9

FROM 
    [tableName]

GROUP BY 
        [Column1]
       ,[Column2]
       ,[Column3]
       ,[Column4]
```

What I am trying to do is also find the column either 'Column1', 'Column2', or 'Column3' that corresponds to the MIN([Column6]) and then the column that corresponds to MAX([Column8]).

The output should be exactly the same except there will be an extra 2 column at the end specifying which one the min and max are associated with.

Comment: simply `HAVING Column1 = MIN([Column6]) AND Column1 = MAX([Column8])` not working?

Comment: Your column labels are not correct, please update MIN([Column5]) AS minColumn5 not max, plus MAX([Column6]) AS maxColumn6 not min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simple problem in your question, as Col1,Col2,Col3 that correspond to the max or min, are displayed directly, in other words you have them as you are grouping by Col1,Col2,Col3 & Col4.
As you did not provide some data, I will set some random data to prove my point.
Lets create a memory table similar to yours with 9 columns and fill it with random data for col6-8 with 10 rows for example, you can use the below:-

```
Declare @data Table(
Column1 int,Column2 int,Column3 int,Column4 int,Column5 int,Column6 int,Column7 int,Column8 int,Column9 int
)
declare @index int=5
while(@index>0)
begin
    insert into @data values(1,2,3,4,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000)
    insert into @data values(5,6,7,8,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000)
    set @index=@index-1
end
```

we can see the data with the below

```
select * from @data  order BY [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4]

Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9
1   2   3   4   669 203 278 364 577
1   2   3   4   389 316 290 548 661
1   2   3   4   835 555 942 985 604
1   2   3   4   477 743 580 305 414
1   2   3   4   431 296 471 150 352
1   2   3   4   346 220 573 941 633
1   2   3   4   392 450 652 978 883
1   2   3   4   235 479 751 136 978
1   2   3   4   906 183 141 915 783
1   2   3   4   329 342 682 977 870
5   6   7   8   218 740 41  299 816
5   6   7   8   800 630 674 888 799
5   6   7   8   27  307 446 743 345
5   6   7   8   501 928 824 592 691
5   6   7   8   439 624 260 757 547
5   6   7   8   287 610 287 708 652
5   6   7   8   441 711 433 642 343
5   6   7   8   751 928 237 53  535
5   6   7   8   594 768 708 173 33
5   6   7   8   352 703 943 867 661
```

now lets see the result of your grouping that you provided without any change

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    minCol5 maxCol6 maxCol8 sumCol7 sumCol8 sumCol9
  1      2       3       4        235   743      985     5360    6299    6755
  5      6       7       8        27    928      888     4853    5722    5422
```

so if we go back to your question, what is the value of Col1,Col2,Col3 for the maxCol6, well for each maxCol6 you have the values of Col1,Col2,Col3 & even Col4. 
so what are the values for Col1,Col2,Col3 for maxCol16 that is 928, well they are 5,6 & 7.

ok, now lets say you want the record key that have that maxCol6, that is easy too, we would add an identity col as ID as below:-

```
Declare @data Table(
ID int identity(1,1), Column1 int,Column2 int,Column3 int,Column4 int,Column5 int,Column6 int,Column7 int,Column8 int,Column9 int
)
declare @index int=10
while(@index>0)
begin
    insert into @data values(1,2,3,4,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000)
    insert into @data values(5,6,7,8,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000,RAND()*1000)
    set @index=@index-1
end
select * from @data  order BY [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4]

;with agg as (
    SELECT 
           [Column1]
          ,[Column2]
          ,[Column3]
          ,[Column4]
          ,MIN([Column5]) AS minColumn5
          ,MAX([Column6]) AS maxColumn6
          ,MAX([Column8]) AS maxColumn8
          ,SUM([Column7]) AS sumColumn7
          ,SUM([Column8]) AS sumColumn8
          ,SUM([Column9]) AS sumColumn9
    FROM 
       @data [tableName]
    GROUP BY 
            [Column1]
           ,[Column2]
           ,[Column3]
           ,[Column4]

)
--select * from agg order BY [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4]
select agg.*,maxCol6.ID [MaxCol6Seq],maxCol8.ID [MaxCol8Seq]  from agg 
    inner join @data maxCol6
        on      agg.Column1=maxCol6.Column1 
            and agg.Column2=maxCol6.Column2
            and agg.Column3=maxCol6.Column3 
            and agg.Column4=maxCol6.Column4 
            and agg.maxColumn6=maxCol6.Column6
    inner join @data maxCol8
        on      agg.Column1=maxCol8.Column1 
            and agg.Column2=maxCol8.Column2
            and agg.Column3=maxCol8.Column3 
            and agg.Column4=maxCol8.Column4 
            and agg.maxColumn8=maxCol8.Column8
```

As this is a new run for this set of data , below:-

```
ID  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9
1   1   2   3   4   201 848 993 50  304
3   1   2   3   4   497 207 644 399 104
5   1   2   3   4   445 321 822 151 185
7   1   2   3   4   611 402 620 61  543
9   1   2   3   4   460 409 182 915 211
11  1   2   3   4   886 804 180 213 282
13  1   2   3   4   614 709 932 806 162
15  1   2   3   4   795 752 110 474 463
17  1   2   3   4   737 545 77  648 727
19  1   2   3   4   788 862 266 464 851
20  5   6   7   8   218 561 943 572 54
18  5   6   7   8   741 621 610 214 536
16  5   6   7   8   579 248 374 693 761
14  5   6   7   8   866 415 198 528 657
12  5   6   7   8   905 947 500 50  387
10  5   6   7   8   492 860 948 299 220
8   5   6   7   8   861 328 727 40  327
6   5   6   7   8   435 534 707 769 777
4   5   6   7   8   587 68  45  184 614
2   5   6   7   8   189 24  289 121 772
```

The result is as below:-

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  minC5   maxC6   maxC8   sumC7   sumC8   sumC9   MaxCol6Seq  MaxCol8Seq
1   2   3   4   201      862    915      4826   4181    3832    19           9
5   6   7   8   189      947    769      5341   3470    5105    12           6
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a flag on each row specifying whether the value is the overall maximum or minimum, you can use window functions and `CASE`:

```
SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4],
       MAX([Column5]) AS maxColumn5,
       MIN([Column6]) AS minColumn6,
       SUM([Column7]) AS sumColumn7,
       SUM([Column8]) AS sumColumn8,
       SUM([Column9]) AS sumColumn9,
       (CASE WHEN MIN([Column6]) = MIN(MIN([Column6])) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as is_min_column6,
       (CASE WHEN MAX([Column7]) = MAX(MAX([Column7])) OVER () THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as is_max_column7
FROM [tableName]
GROUP BY [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your method and that didn't work :( I'm thinking now that maybe it could work to use Row_NUMBER() to pull out row number of the min/max and then somehow link that row number back to the original table.

Comment: @josh0798 . . . "didn't work" is not helpful.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.